# Couldn't find driver when use pdo to connect to mssql in php

Tags: php, pdo

I've downloaded and installed drivers in phpext. When I check phpinfo(), figure out drivers installed successfully. But when I use this code to check connection:

```
$dsn = 'mssql:host=localhost;dbname=chat';
$user = 'sa';
$password = '123';
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This exception appears:

> Connection failed: could not find driver
>   Could you please help me?

Comment: Working on Windows or Linux?

Comment: The exception says *"Could you please help me?"* Love it. ;-P

Comment: In windows @user2486495

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your phpinfo() output.

Comment: Try using php_pdo_sqlsrv $dsn = 'sqlsrv:host=   ....

Comment: Also,  in ref to above make sure you have the native client installed.  the exact version of the client will depend on the version of the driver.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff658533.aspx

Comment: @Gavin Doesn't work with sqlsrv. U uploaded image that show phpinfo

Comment: You should be using pdo_sql_sqlsrv there is some information here on connection strings which might help.  http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Comment: Thank you @Gavin for your attention. I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you @Gavin. It's work. Please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using pdo_sql_sqlsrv rather than msssql.

Please make sure that you have the correct sqlsrv extension installed, and that you use an appropriate connection string https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

```
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:host= ....
```

In many cases when using the sqlsrv extension you will also need to install a compatible version of the sql native client:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff658533.aspx

Comment: I am using an older version of Red Hat and PHP. The SQLSRV drivers aren't available to me.